# Django simplejwt JWTAuthentication Permission

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication in Django to create tokens for our users.
But some users have limited user permissions[in the admin panel]. For example they only allow to get articles and nothing else. But the token that simplejwt creates allow user to get all other data as well.

Is there a way to adjust it? I think simplejwt overwrites the Django permissions.

Answer (score 2):

The token is used just for Authentication purposes, not for Authorisation purposes. You need to use permissions for assigning permissions to different users. Read about django permissions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization). If you need to customize permissions, you can extend DjangoModelPermissions class.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I know it's for Authentication, but the problem is, with this token it creates for the user[that already have limited Authorisation], the user can access all the data. That's the problem!

Comment: If it has limited Authorisation as you say, how can user access all the data? There must be something you are missing

Comment: That's the question: what am I missing? Here is an image of AdminPanel to show you the user permission:
[link]https://ibb.co/9bjWfBC